A function similar to the ackerman function , how to get its non recursive form through alogrithm

it's suppose to be a homework for data structure and alogrithm
i googled through all websites and still cannont figure it out
i tried to use a stack to store my pair(n,m)
but its hard to set it correct for the situation greater than 1
need help from the community

I think this is better suited for a different Stack Exchange site.
